# CSS not working on Html.ActionLink

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html.actionlink

I'm trying to add CSS to an ActionLink to make it a clickable image, but it's not working.

Here is my ActionLink:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Account", new { @class="logoutButton"})
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.logoutButton {
background: url(../Images/logout_icon.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: I would suggest changing the background to a color, that will let you know if its an issue with the image url.

Comment: It was indeed an issue with image url. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your directory path is correct?

Can you use your tools in your browser (F12 normally) to verify that path is finding your resource, or even that the CSS has "found" your object?

I use the right-click "inspect" frequently to see what CSS is finding and modifying my object.

Comment: I followed your advice and apparently the patch to the image was wrong. I fixed it and it works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help (and I assume you meant "path") :)